# kernel module inside of LXC container

Tags: linux, namespaces, lxc

Is my understanding correct that kernel modules are NOT supposed to be loaded inside of LXC, and only must be loaded on the host, since containers share the host's kernel ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can install kernel modules inside LXC just like any linux system. But there are seccomp extensions that you can use to prevent installing modules inside LXC, once configured insmod will fail.